# unable to make a vertical bar appear as bold

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have two vertical bars in html appear as bold but this this to be impossible.

html:

```
<html>
<body>
aaa <b>||</b> aaa <b>bbb</b>
</body>
</html>
```

i also tried with

```
<span style='font-weight: bold;'>||</span>
```

but it's impossible.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2WXA/1/

any ideas?

Comment: What font-family are you using?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me... Try giving it a specific font-family. Different browsers have different default fonts-families. I'm using Chrome and there is definitely a difference when I change the font-weight to 'normal'.

Comment: Works for me (default font is Verdana 16). http://i.stack.imgur.com/NIm0e.png

Comment: Probably is your web browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are bold:

[image]

Increase your zoom to check it. Or change your `font-family`, for example, to `Arial`.

Check here `Arial` bold `||`: http://jsfiddle.net/n2WXA/2/

Comment: Same result as @FSou1, I confirm.

Comment: yes it seems i have to define a font style, like arial or verdana for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can fake thickness with text-shadow, no matter the font-family: http://jsfiddle.net/n2WXA/3/

```
text-shadow: 1px 0 0
```

Comment: +1, not bad solution, but this property `IE` accept only from version 10 :)